# Performing accuracy assessment using actual vs predicted values in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I am intending to perform validation of the derived soil thickness raster to evaluation its accuracy in terms of RMSE. I already have actual and corresponding predicted values extracted from the model.

Can anyone help me to validate my soil thickness model>

Comment: What have you tried, in  any single  GIS application, to try and answer your own question prior to posting?

Comment: The aim is to compare the predicted value to the observed value in order to obtain RMSE. I tried 'ArcGIS Cross Validation' tool but it takes only geostatistical layer.

Comment: If you are wanting to ask about how to do this in ArcGIS Desktop then please write that in your question.  And be sure to let us know what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I've re-opened your question but I will not be surprised to see it attract close votes for being too broad.  You are only telling us what you want to do, and not precisely what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I've used multiple linear regression to produce soil thickness model in raster format. Now, I am not sure how to validate my raster in ArcGIS to know difference between my actual and predicted values in terms of RMSE.

Comment: Please keep editing your question rather than creating a comment trail that potential answerers may or may not read.